# XSLT 2.0 skip all elements except one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a request with some elements with structure like below:

```
<Request>
      <Other>
      ...
      </Other>
      <Qualifiers>
         <Options>
            <Segment Number="1"/>
         </Options> 
         <Offer>
            <Column ColumnNumber="2.1"/>
            <Record Number="2"/>
         </Offer>
         <Offer>
            <Column ColumnNumber="1.1"/>
            <Column EndColumnNumber="4.1" ColumnNumber="3.1"/>
            <Record Number="1"/>
         </Offer>
         <Offer>
            <Column ColumnNumber="5.1"/>
            <Record Number="3"/>
         </Offer>
         <Fare>
            <Basis>ABCDE</Basis>
         </Fare>
      </Qualifiers>
      <Other>
      ...
      </Other>
</Request>
```

From this payload I need to do 3 separate requests with single Offer element in each call. The rest of request should be copied without changes, so for first Offer my request should looks like that:

```
<Request>
      <Other>
      ...
      </Other>
      <Qualifiers>
         <Options>
            <Segment Number="1"/>
         </Options>
         <Offer>
            <Column ColumnNumber="2.1"/>
            <Record Number="2"/>
         </Offer>
         <Fare>
            <Basis>ABCDE</Basis>
         </Fare>
      </Qualifiers>
      <Other>
      ...
      </Other>
</Request>
```

Second and third analogical with second and third Offer elements.

I use Camel, so I tried to make it in loop providing to XSLT parameter which is index of the element which should be left. So, I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Request/Qualifiers/Offer[not($MY_IDX)]"/>
```

Where `$MY_IDX` is provided index. After some searchings I realised that it won't worked, because `not()` function takes and returns only boolean value. 
Is there any other way to archive my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:template match="/Request/Qualifiers/Offer[not($MY_IDX)]"/>
```

use

```
<xsl:template match="/Request/Qualifiers/Offer[position() != $MY_IDX]" />
```

which suppresses all but the `Offer` whose position is given by `$MY_IDX`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly